# Arma 3 Epoch cant join server

Tags: arma-3, epoch

I installed Epoch to the arma 3 directory and enabled it in expansions. When i try to join a server i get kicked of with no message, i can see the lobby for a fraction of a second and thats it. Any solution?

Comment: That normally tends to mean that you do not meet the requirements for the server (normally missing mods). Have you changed the command line for Arma to include the mod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling the mod using Play withsix launcher seemed to have fixed the problem.
here is a link if you have the problem aswell: http://play.withsix.com/